# Как с помощью OpenXML подсчитать кол-во страниц в docx документе?

Tags: c#, openxml

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
var pageCount = document.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Pages.InnerText.ToString();
```

Возвращает "1", хотя в документе 4 страницы.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Это [известный баг](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/issues/22). Microsoft советует для подсчета страниц использовать Word. Возможно, другие библиотеки могут подойти (ClosedXml, NPOI, ...)

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d1d31ad5-4ce3-49db-801e-b81c59281572/get-ms-word-page-count-using-open-xml?forum=oxmlsdk) предлагают такое решение:

```
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName, false))
{
  int pageCount = (int) document.ExtendedFilePropertiesPart.Properties.Pages.Text;
}
```

Comment: Я так и делаю сейчас. У меня проблема в другом. Изначально есть каркас docx, там действительно одна страница. Но потом я программно добавляю туда параграфы, и в конце (после всех добавлений) я считаю кол-во страниц, именно так, как вы предложили, я тоже видел этот пример. Но он по-прежнему возвращает "1".

Comment: А вы пробовали сохранить документ, а потом сосчитать?

Comment: Я не знаю как там сделать сохранение. Я использовал два using. В первом добавлял параграфы. А во втором считал кол-во страниц. Разве в WordprocessingDocument есть метод save? Я думал он автоматически сохраняется.

Comment: Хотя я сейчас делаю так: `document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();` перед подсчетом страниц. Но все равно возвращается "1".